# Boot disk problems

Tags: boot, disk

Followed the download instructions for making USB bootable for 14.04.01 on borrowed iMac as laptop needs a clean boot. Copied command line from instructions and pasted into terminal, returns  error cannot convert multiple files?  This from ISO download.

Comment: Please post the error message and the command that leads to it.